# Project Directory Tree on TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, visual-sourcesafe

I'm migrating from VSS to TFS 2010 and using that as a good opportunity to review how we organize projects in the company.

Our company deals with two market segments, let's say Sports and Industrial Inspection. Since there's a low likelihood of sharing projects or code from one codebase to another, I created two project collections, one for sports and one for inspection.

The thing is that developers are used to the VSS way of organizing projects by creating a directory tree where the projects go.

How that concept migrates to TFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find [TFS branching guide](http://tfsbranchingguideiii.codeplex.com/) to be a good starting point for project structure in TFS. Look at the TFS_Branching_Guide_Main_2010_v1.pdf file in the zip that one downloads. There are some good examples in there.

Answer (score 0):

I think that splitting the two market segments into two project collections was a good idea.  Keep in mind your project structure in each collection if you are planning on using the TFS Work Items.  Most work item templates that I am aware of only allow project tracking by team project.  For example:  If your development team is working on two projects at the same time and you wont be able to run separate TFS project tracking reports for each project.  In that case you will need to create a collection for each project.

Once you have all your files ported over from VSS in a directory structure you are comfortable with, I would then look into a branching strategy that your team agrees on.

I hope this is useful.